# Form.Show method error C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, error-handling

I have a problem. I have this code:

```
.....
Form11.show();
.....
```

Why it does not works? My IDE is shouting on me:
http://prntscr.com/2kfkw
Why? How can I repair it? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think "show" should be capitalized.  Second, you want to create an instance of your form, then show it:

```
        Form1 myForm = new Form1();
        myForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is case sensitive; the method name you want is probably Show().

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
new Form11().Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be a capital S on the method name, i.e. `Form1.Show();`

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive. Use

`Form11.Show();`

instead of

`Form11.show();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Form11 form = new Form11();
 form.Show();
```